# Angular2: Not able to navigate to child routes directly

Tags: angular, nested-routes, angular-component-router

I have created routes like this

```
{path: 'trainings', component: TrainingWrapperComponent,
  children:[
    {path: '', component: TrainingsListComponent},
    {path: 'createTraining', component: ManageTrainingComponent},
    {path: 'trainingLanguage', component: TrainingLanguageComponent},

  ]
  },
```

Now when I navigate to child route from trainings, I am able to do it. But if I refresh or I try to open the url directly. I am not able to do that.

For instance trainings/createTraining is throwing http errors because it is trying to fetch resources by taking training/ as the base url .

Comment: May you post the code part where the route is called please ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. You have: <base href="/"> in the index.html? Isn't it the webserver than doesnt understand the routes. Does it also occur when you use HashLocationStrategy?

Comment: I am navigating like this:
 <button class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['trainings/createTraining']" type="button">Create Training</button>
It works from here, but a refresh after navigation doesnt work and also when I try to navigate to localhost/trainings/createTraining, it doesnt work as well

Comment: @MarcelHoekstra yes I have base href defines in index.html. Also I am currectly using browsersync to run my project. Can that be an issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. I finally found the solution. The problem was that the server was not able to recognise my child routes as part of the angular route and thus that error. So, the simplest solution was to change the location strategy used for routing to hashlocationstategy. This immediately solved the problem.

Comment: same worked for me, oddly enough i still cant directly go to any /route directly without doing /#/route

or is this only possible through ngninx route rewriting?

Comment: can you please elaborate on that?